# How to connect to HSQL which Spring creates when jdbc:embedded-database is used?

Tags: spring, hsqldb

I have a HSQL database which Spring automatically creates for me:

```
<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="HSQL">
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:scheme.sql" /
</jdbc:embedded-database>
```

And now I want to connect to this database. My question is how to do this, because I don't known which address I should use.

Comment: What do you mean by "connect to"? Do you want to use it in your spring bean or you want to connect with external database browser?

Comment: @peter-gwiazda I mean how to connect to it with external database browser.

Comment: Run HSQLDB in server mode. You can also check H2 database.

Comment: roytuts.com/embedded-hsql-database-with-spring/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This embedded HSQL database is all-in-memory and in-process, therefore accessible only from the Spring Java process. If you want to access the database from another tool as well, for example to check the contents with a database manager, you can start an HSQLDB server with an all-in-memory instance, then connect to the server from Spring and other tools.

This is covered in the HSQLDB Guide http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/listeners-chapt.html

The server is started with this command:

```
java -cp ../lib/hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.Server --database.0 mem:test --dbname.0 test
```

You need to create a Spring data source with username "SA" and password "". The database driver and URL (from the same machine) to configure the Spring data source are:

```
org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/test
```

Comment: When I run `java -cp ~/.m2/repository/org/hsqldb/hsqldb/2.0.0/hsqldb-2.0.0.jar org.hsqldb.util.DatabaseManagerSwing` and use `jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/test` I've got error: `java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: java.net.ConnextException: Connection refused`

Comment: java -cp ../lib/hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.Server... is running without an error?

Comment: @peter-gwiazda When I run server manually, I can connect to it with provided command. But in my case, Spring starts server, so I ask about how to connect to HSQL which runned by Spring..

Comment: It's rather impossible. You have to run server manually and connect with Spring app and other applications. In embeded mode you can only access in the same JVM. What's wrong with server mode? What do you keep in the DB? Why restart DB every time with application?

Comment: You were right that I can't connect to HSQL from another JVM process. I have used H2 console to accomplish that. Today I've found another way to achieve that with Spring and HSQL: http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-view-content-of-hsqldb-embedded-database/

Comment: Note that to run HSQLDB in server mode (which allows connections from external clients), you don't need to start it in a separate process.  You can embed it in your application by instantiating an `org.hsqldb.server.Server` object.

Answer (score 7):

I recomend you to use external Database, but just in case if you want to use HSQL, then this may will help you http://java.dzone.com/articles/spring-3-makes-use-embedded-easy

Comment: +1, in addition Transactional annotation for ContextConfiguration integration tests will rollback by default making the development db safe and consistent after testing.

Answer (score 2):

Embedded-database is an in memory DB and Spring supports HSQL, H2, and Derby . You could go to their respective site for the connection details .

For H2 see [here](http://www.h2database.com/html/faq.html#connect) .
For HSQL see [here](http://hsqldb.org/web/hsqlFAQ.html#NEWDB) and [here](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch01.html#N101CA).

As far as I understand , the

```
<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="HSQL">
  <jdbc:script location="classpath:scheme.sql" /
</jdbc:embedded-database>
```

uses an in-memory DB and so is not accessible externally . You'll be able to access this within the same VM and same class loader .

Comment: Can we use XML file to load into DB

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to the embedded database in the normal fashion, (SQL Developer, SQL Explorer etc); I used my debugger to look at the URL property in the embedded database bean I created with Spring, in your case dataSource.  I would think your url would be something along the lines of `jdbc:hsqldb:mem:dataSource`.

Comment: It definitely won't work because in-memory database available only inside one JVM process.

Answer (score 0):

For some people a sufficient solution would be to use the h2 console - as described here:

[spring boot default H2 jdbc connection (and H2 console)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24655684/spring-boot-default-h2-jdbc-connection-and-h2-console)

You must only remember to set hsqldb drivers where needed. This way the database doesn't have to be started separately. You also don't have to install any additional software to browse it.

Answer (score -1):

you can do like this

```
final ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("dao-context.xml");
final DataSource dataSource = (DataSource)ctx.getBean("dataSource");
final Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
```