# H2 database console spring boot Load denied by X-Frame-Options

Tags: h2, spring-boot, spring-4

I`m building a skeletal project for dev with spring 4 boot security and others.
Using H2 while attempting to log into the db console and manage my db i get the following error. The page is blank, with 4 bugs in firebug konsole :

```
 Load denied by X-Frame-Options: http://localhost:8080/console
```

With links to

```
/header.jsp?jsessionid=f71207a702c9177e57208414721bbe93 does not permit framing.
/query.jsp?jsessionid=f71207a702c9177e57208414721bbe93 does not permit framing.
/help.jsp?jsessionid=f71207a702c9177e57208414721bbe93 does not permit framing.
/tables.do?jsessionid=f71207a702c9177e57208414721bbe93 does not permit framing.
```

1. I can test the connection from console level - its ok.
2. DB works fine, import.sql works fine, i can create user entities withing spring is starting up.

The configuration i am using is from (and it works on spring 3.2 with xml configuration)

[spring boot default H2 jdbc connection (and H2 console)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24655684/spring-boot-default-h2-jdbc-connection-and-h2-console)

Using : 
        spring-boot-starter-parent
        1.1.4.RELEASE

Comment: Added 
 .and().headers()
 .addHeaderWriter(new XFrameOptionsHeaderWriter(
                  new WhiteListedAllowFromStrategy(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:8080","http://localhost"))))

White page and info to refresh to page to get the source code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Added the code below to Application.java and for now it works, default on port 8082, starts with spring app. It doesn`t hit the spot but for dev purposes it is all ok.

```
@Bean
org.h2.tools.Server h2Server() {
    Server server = new Server();
    try {
        server.runTool("-tcp");
        server.runTool("-tcpAllowOthers");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return server;

}
```

Comment: Nice but is automatically starting h2 in browser on startup, is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: I spent 3 hours trying to make it work via Spring Security and could not. This did the trick!

Answer (score 73):

It's also possible to simplify the answer from @chrosciu with this:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
  }
}
```

Comment: Or, more securely, `headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin()`.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.headers().addHeaderWriter(
            new XFrameOptionsHeaderWriter(
                new WhiteListedAllowFromStrategy(Arrays.asList("localhost"))));
    }
}
```

Of course contents of white list should be adjusted in case when application is running on something different than localhost.

Comment: Even better solution: `http.headers().addHeaderWriter(new XFrameOptionsHeaderWriter(XFrameOptionsMode.SAMEORIGIN));` This  does not require to explicite state host name in secuiryty config

Comment: Even better: `.headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin()`

Answer (score 0):

With new spring `dsl` you can use `headers` method in `SecurityFilterChain` as below

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration  {

  @Bean
  SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.headers(headers -> headers.frameOptions().disable()) //disable frame
        //rest of your configuration
        .csrf( csrf -> csrf.disable())
        .authorizeHttpRequests(
                    authorize -> authorize
                            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/users", "/users/login").permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/articles/**").permitAll()
                            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            )
          
        return http.build();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Most answers are fine but they do mess with the security config for the entire application, not only the H2 console. A better way - assuming a development environment - would therefore be to simply add an exception to the entire security config:

```java
@Bean
SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http
    // exclude H2 requests
    .requestMatcher(
      new NegatedRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/h2-console/**"))
    )
    // default security config
    .authorizeRequests()
      .anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```