# Converting Spring WebSecurityConfig from Spring 1 to Spring 3

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am converting a Spring 1 application to Spring 3. I have tried to replace the configure function with SecurityFilterChain, but I seem to be missing something. I get an error about a possible circular reference. Any assistance converting the WebSecurityConfig would be appreciated. The application has also been updated to Java 17 and is startable using maven.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Component
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Value("${web.WebSecurityConfig.gen_hashpass:false}")
private Boolean gen_hashpass;

@Autowired
private WebUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
private DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

@Autowired
private WebCasAuthenticationProvider vwCasAuthenticationProvider;

/**
 * Set the authentication provider for this application
 *
 * @param auth
 * @throws Exception
 */
@Autowired
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
    auth.authenticationProvider(vwCasAuthenticationProvider);
}

/**
 * Instantiate the authentication provider for this application
 *
 * @return Instance of DaoAuthenticationProvider
 */
@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = WebUser.getPasswordEncoder();

    authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);

    // Generate encrypted starter password for testing if requested via 
application.properties
    String hashPass = passwordEncoder.encode("bar");
    if (gen_hashpass) {
        System.out.println(hashPass);
    }

    return authProvider;
}

@Bean
public WebCasAuthenticationProvider vwCasAuthenticationProvider() {
    WebCasAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new WebCasAuthenticationProvider();
    return authProvider;
}



/**
 * Define the URL-level security settings + login flow for the application
 *
 * @param http
 * @throws Exception
 */
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    //http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
    http.csrf().disable();
    http
            .headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin() // Gem from 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30108247/773376 to allow IFRAMEs
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(
                    "/",
                    "/css/**",
                    "/js/**",
                    "/images/**",
                    "/favicon.ico",
                    "/favicon-epi.ico",
                    "/debug/**",
                    "/app/**",
                    "/register",
                    "/confirm",
                    "/confirm/*",
                    "/password-reset",
                    "/password-reset/*",
                    "/reset-password",
                    "/reset-password/*",
                    "/model/**",
                    "/modal/**",
                    "/project/*",
                    "/user/**",
                    "/feedback",
                    "/monitoring/**",
                    "/terms-of-service",
                    "/privacy-policy",
                    "/api/logging/*",
                    "/sso/**",
                    "/announcement/*",
                    "/library/*",
                    "/docs/**",
                    "/api/eol/*",
                    "/eol/model/**",
                    "/researcher/join-experiment"
            ).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/modal/login")
            // .defaultSuccessUrl("/modal/login-success", true)
            .successHandler(new LoginSuccessHandler())
            .permitAll()
        .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
            .permitAll();
}

}
```

Comment: Follow the migration guide: First migrate to 2.X and then to 3.X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Component
public class WebSecurityConfig {

@Bean
static DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(WebUserDetailsService userDetailsService,@Value("${web.WebSecurityConfig.gen_hashpass:false}")Boolean gen_hashpass) {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = WebUser.getPasswordEncoder();

    authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);

    // Generate encrypted starter password for testing if requested via
    application.properties
    String hashPass = passwordEncoder.encode("bar");
    if (gen_hashpass) {
        System.out.println(hashPass);
    }

    return authProvider;
}

@Bean
static WebCasAuthenticationProvider vwCasAuthenticationProvider() {
    return new WebCasAuthenticationProvider();
}

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider, WebCasAuthenticationProvider vwCasAuthenticationProvider) throws Exception {
    http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider).authenticationProvider(vwCasAuthenticationProvider);
    return http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .headers(c->c.frameOptions(HeadersConfigurer.FrameOptionsConfig::sameOrigin))
            .authorizeHttpRequests(c->c.requestMatchers(
                    "/",
                    "/css/**",
                    "/js/**",
                    "/images/**",
                    "/favicon.ico",
                    "/favicon-epi.ico",
                    "/debug/**",
                    "/app/**",
                    "/register",
                    "/confirm",
                    "/confirm/*",
                    "/password-reset",
                    "/password-reset/*",
                    "/reset-password",
                    "/reset-password/*",
                    "/model/**",
                    "/modal/**",
                    "/project/*",
                    "/user/**",
                    "/feedback",
                    "/monitoring/**",
                    "/terms-of-service",
                    "/privacy-policy",
                    "/api/logging/*",
                    "/sso/**",
                    "/announcement/*",
                    "/library/*",
                    "/docs/**",
                    "/api/eol/*",
                    "/eol/model/**",
                    "/researcher/join-experiment"
            ).permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated())
            .formLogin(c->c.loginPage("/modal/login").successHandler(new LoginSuccessHandler()).permitAll())
            .logout(c->c.logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll())
            .build();
}

}
```