# Why does the H2 console in Spring Boot show a blank screen after logging in?

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2

I'm using Spring Boot 1.4.1 with the H2 database.  I have enabled the H2 console as described in the [reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-sql-h2-console) by adding the following lines to my application.properties file:

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2
```

When I go to the H2 console in Chrome 53 for Windows, I can see the login page and clicking the "Test Connection" button results in "Test successful":

[image]

But when I click on the "Connect" button, the screen turns completely blank.  When I view the source, I see "Sorry, Lynx not supported yet" (see the [full source](http://pastebin.com/XFyJL2de)).  The same thing happens in Firefox.

Why is that happening?  I believe I am using the correct JDBC URL, as 4 different people posted on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24655684/spring-boot-default-h2-jdbc-connection-and-h2-console) that you should use `jdbc:h2:mem:testdb`.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

According to a [blog post](http://shengwangi.blogspot.com/2016/02/how-to-use-h2-embeded-database-in-spring.html), a line needs to be added to 
the `configure` method of the `SecurityConfig` class if you have the `spring-boot-starter-security` dependency in your project, otherwise you will see an empty page after logging into the H2 console:

```
http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
```

I added that line and it solved the problem.

Alternatively, the following line can be used (as mentioned [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7198)):

```
http.headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();
```

Comment: That sounds like a bug in Spring Boot. I've opened https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7198 so that we can investigate.

Comment: I second sashok_bg's suggestion.

Answer (score 8):

I can resolve the same problem using the following code in my SecurityConfig class

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    bla();
    bla();   
    http.headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();
}
```

I don't know what this line does, maybe someone with more experience can explain it.

Comment: All the information present in XFrameOptionsHeaderWriter: it is adding header "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN". It works for me as well (although, I'm using ModHeader extension for Chrome instead of modifying the code).

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your application.properties

```
 security.headers.frame=false
```

Comment: I have tried that, but it says "Property 'security.headers.frame' is Deprecated: The security auto-configuration is no longer customizable. Provide your own WebSecurityConfigurer bean instead." And it doesn't seem to fix the problem. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Along with the answer by @pacoverflow note the following:

As of Spring Boot 2.3.4. The DB Name is printed in the console:
[image]
Connect using that DB name:
[image]