# H2-Console is not showing in browser

Tags: spring-boot, h2

I am working on SpringBoot api and using H2 database with following property settings.

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.name=test
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.datasource.initialization-mode = embedded
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

When I want to use browser to view the H2 database console through 'http://localhost:8082/h2-console', a screen open in browser with connect and test connection button. When I click on Test Connection, it returns successful but when click on Connect button, error comes that localhost refused to connect.

[image: Here is the screen of that error]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the H2 console in Spring Boot show a blank screen after logging in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40165915/why-does-the-h2-console-in-spring-boot-show-a-blank-screen-after-logging-in)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

add this two lines in your spring security file and you are good to go.

```
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
```

Answer (score 20):

By default Spring Security disables rendering within an [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) because allowing a webpage to be added to a frame can be a security issue, for example [Clickjacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking). Since H2 console runs within a frame so while Spring security is enabled,  frame options has to be  disabled explicitly, in order to get the H2 console working.

```
http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
```

In general there are two possible directives for [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options), which are DENY or SAMEORIGIN, so the following configuration can also be used for restricted but secured access.

```
headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();
```

This allows the page to be displayed in a frame on the same origin as the page itself

Comment: Your answer is the most completest and the safest one. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Apart from @Alien's response, I had to add `http.csrf().disable();` also.

Answer (score 0):

Added following line one application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

spring.h2.console.enabled=true
```

And also added following on pom.xml

```xml
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <configuration>
        <jdbc>
          <driver>org.h2.Driver</driver>
          <url>jdbc:h2:~/test</url>
        </jdbc>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
<build>
```

Answer (score 0):

For **Spring Boot 3+** and **Spring Security 6**, add following lines into your **SecurityFilterChain** Bean. The newer versions of Spring security heavily use lambda expressions for configurations. The following lines use method references in Java 8+.

```
.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
.headers(httpSecurityHeadersConfigurer -> {
    httpSecurityHeadersConfigurer.frameOptions(HeadersConfigurer.FrameOptionsConfig::disable);
 })
```

The above code without method reference is as follows.

```
.csrf(httpSecurityCsrfConfigurer -> httpSecurityCsrfConfigurer.disable())
.headers(httpSecurityHeadersConfigurer -> {
     httpSecurityHeadersConfigurer.frameOptions(frameOptionsConfig -> {
                    frameOptionsConfig.disable();
     });
})
```

However besides the above code, you need to properly configure the h2 database, enable h2-console in the *application.properties* file and permit the access to the h2-console like below within the SecurityFilterChain Bean.

```
.authorizeHttpRequests(registry -> {
  registry.requestMatchers("/console/**").permitAll();
})
```