# Spring Boot/H2 Console not showing my table

Tags: spring, spring-boot, h2

I've tried many of the solutions given on Stackoverflow for that problem but none of them worked for me.
This is my H2 Console login page:
[image: LOGIN PAGE]

my console:

[image: CONSOLE]

my "application.properties" is on default right now:

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
```

mydb.sql:

```
create table members
(
  id integer not null,
  firstname varchar(250) not null,
  lastname varchar(250),
  phonenumber integer,
  created timestamp,
  primary key(id)
);
```

Eclipse console:

```
2017-10-30 16:37:17.810  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] c.r.s.SpringbootdbApplication            : Starting SpringbootdbApplication on ISRTLVM740 with PID 10520 (C:\Users\apodga\javaworkspace2\springbootdb\target\classes started by apodga in C:\Users\apodga\javaworkspace2\springbootdb)
2017-10-30 16:37:17.810  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] c.r.s.SpringbootdbApplication            : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-10-30 16:37:17.872  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@77f9494a: startup date [Mon Oct 30 16:37:17 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-10-30 16:37:19.159  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'httpRequestHandlerAdapter' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration; factoryMethodName=httpRequestHandlerAdapter; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration; factoryMethodName=httpRequestHandlerAdapter; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]]
2017-10-30 16:37:19.880  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7765ff64] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-10-30 16:37:21.009  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-10-30 16:37:21.024  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2017-10-30 16:37:21.024  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.23
2017-10-30 16:37:21.134  INFO 10520 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-10-30 16:37:21.134  INFO 10520 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3262 ms
2017-10-30 16:37:21.322  INFO 10520 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-10-30 16:37:21.322  INFO 10520 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'webServlet' to [/h2-console/*]
2017-10-30 16:37:21.337  INFO 10520 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-10-30 16:37:21.337  INFO 10520 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-10-30 16:37:21.337  INFO 10520 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-10-30 16:37:21.337  INFO 10520 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-10-30 16:37:21.618  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : testdb - Starting...
2017-10-30 16:37:21.977  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : testdb - Start completed.
2017-10-30 16:37:22.039  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-10-30 16:37:22.055  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2017-10-30 16:37:22.165  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.11.Final}
2017-10-30 16:37:22.165  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2017-10-30 16:37:22.212  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2017-10-30 16:37:22.352  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2017-10-30 16:37:22.649  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.t.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl  : HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@64d941ca'
2017-10-30 16:37:22.649  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-10-30 16:37:23.594  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@77f9494a: startup date [Mon Oct 30 16:37:17 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-10-30 16:37:23.714  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/members],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.util.List<com.recweb.springbootdb.Member> com.recweb.springbootdb.MemberController.getAllUsers()
2017-10-30 16:37:23.721  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2017-10-30 16:37:23.721  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2017-10-30 16:37:23.769  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-10-30 16:37:23.769  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-10-30 16:37:23.789  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Detected @ExceptionHandler methods in repositoryRestExceptionHandler
2017-10-30 16:37:23.871  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-10-30 16:37:24.094  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerAdapter   : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@77f9494a: startup date [Mon Oct 30 16:37:17 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-10-30 16:37:24.119  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}],methods=[OPTIONS],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.optionsForCollectionResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
2017-10-30 16:37:24.119  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}],methods=[HEAD],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.headCollectionResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DefaultedPageable) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2017-10-30 16:37:24.119  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.hateoas.Resources<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.getCollectionResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DefaultedPageable,org.springframework.data.domain.Sort,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException,org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2017-10-30 16:37:24.119  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/x-spring-data-compact+json || text/uri-list]}" onto public org.springframework.hateoas.Resources<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.getCollectionResourceCompact(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DefaultedPageable,org.springframework.data.domain.Sort,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException,org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2017-10-30 16:37:24.119  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}],methods=[POST],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.postCollectionResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResource,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler,java.lang.String) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2017-10-30 16:37:24.121  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}],methods=[OPTIONS],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.optionsForItemResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
2017-10-30 16:37:24.121  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}],methods=[HEAD],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.headForItemResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2017-10-30 16:37:24.121  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}],methods=[PATCH],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.patchItemResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResource,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.ETag,java.lang.String) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException
2017-10-30 16:37:24.121  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}],methods=[DELETE],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.deleteItemResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.ETag) throws org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException,org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2017-10-30 16:37:24.121  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.Resource<?>> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.getItemResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler,org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2017-10-30 16:37:24.121  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}],methods=[PUT],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<? extends org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.putItemResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResource,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.ETag,java.lang.String) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2017-10-30 16:37:24.126  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}/{property}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.followPropertyReference(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws java.lang.Exception
2017-10-30 16:37:24.126  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}/{property}/{propertyId}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.followPropertyReference(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws java.lang.Exception
2017-10-30 16:37:24.129  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}/{property}],methods=[DELETE],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<? extends org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.deletePropertyReference(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception
2017-10-30 16:37:24.129  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}/{property}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/x-spring-data-compact+json || text/uri-list]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.followPropertyReferenceCompact(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws java.lang.Exception
2017-10-30 16:37:24.129  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}/{property}],methods=[PATCH || PUT || POST],consumes=[application/json || application/x-spring-data-compact+json || text/uri-list],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<? extends org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.createPropertyReference(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.http.HttpMethod,org.springframework.hateoas.Resources<java.lang.Object>,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception
2017-10-30 16:37:24.129  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}/{property}/{propertyId}],methods=[DELETE],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.deletePropertyReferenceId(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception
2017-10-30 16:37:24.131  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/search],methods=[OPTIONS],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.optionsForSearches(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
2017-10-30 16:37:24.134  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/search/{search}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/x-spring-data-compact+json]}" onto public org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.executeSearchCompact(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders,org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DefaultedPageable,org.springframework.data.domain.Sort,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler)
2017-10-30 16:37:24.134  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/search/{search}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.executeSearch(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>,java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DefaultedPageable,org.springframework.data.domain.Sort,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler,org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders)
2017-10-30 16:37:24.134  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/search/{search}],methods=[HEAD],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Object> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.headForSearch(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.lang.String)
2017-10-30 16:37:24.134  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/search/{search}],methods=[OPTIONS],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Object> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.optionsForSearch(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.lang.String)
2017-10-30 16:37:24.136  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/search],methods=[HEAD],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.headForSearches(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
2017-10-30 16:37:24.136  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/search],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchesResource org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.listSearches(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
2017-10-30 16:37:24.136  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/ || ],methods=[OPTIONS],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryController.optionsForRepositories()
2017-10-30 16:37:24.136  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/ || ],methods=[HEAD],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryController.headForRepositories()
2017-10-30 16:37:24.139  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/ || ],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryLinksResource> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryController.listRepositories()
2017-10-30 16:37:24.141  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.BasePathAwareHandlerMapping    : Mapped "{[/profile/{repository}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/alps+json || */*]}" onto org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.alps.AlpsController.descriptor(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
2017-10-30 16:37:24.141  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.BasePathAwareHandlerMapping    : Mapped "{[/profile/{repository}],methods=[OPTIONS],produces=[application/alps+json]}" onto org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.alps.AlpsController.alpsOptions()
2017-10-30 16:37:24.141  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.BasePathAwareHandlerMapping    : Mapped "{[/profile],methods=[GET]}" onto org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ProfileController.listAllFormsOfMetadata()
2017-10-30 16:37:24.141  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.BasePathAwareHandlerMapping    : Mapped "{[/profile],methods=[OPTIONS]}" onto public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ProfileController.profileOptions()
2017-10-30 16:37:24.144  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.BasePathAwareHandlerMapping    : Mapped "{[/profile/{repository}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/schema+json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.JsonSchema> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySchemaController.schema(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
2017-10-30 16:37:24.339  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2017-10-30 16:37:24.456  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-10-30 16:37:24.459  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'dataSource' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2017-10-30 16:37:24.469  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located MBean 'dataSource': registering with JMX server as MBean [com.zaxxer.hikari:name=dataSource,type=HikariDataSource]
2017-10-30 16:37:24.546  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-10-30 16:37:24.554  INFO 10520 --- [  restartedMain] c.r.s.SpringbootdbApplication            : Started SpringbootdbApplication in 7.103 seconds (JVM running for 7.693)
```

I am using Spring Boot v2.0.0.M5.
H2 1.4.196.

Another screenshot that may be useful  :

[image: mydb.sql]

Type, Name & Database are empty but i'm working with a video tutorial and there it's empty too..

Any clue?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so that was silly. When i changed the name of my sql file to "schema.sql", it worked...

Comment: It is because, this default initialization for spring-boot JPA database. For reading: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html

Answer (score 27):

I ran into the same problem and it took a while to find out why tables were missing. In my case I have changed the jdbc url from "jdbc:h2:~/test" to "jdbc:h2:mem:testdb" which is the default h2 database created by spring boot.

Also find comments on [spring boot default H2 jdbc connection (and H2 console)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24655684/spring-boot-default-h2-jdbc-connection-and-h2-console)

Comment: Changing JDBC URL to "jdbc:h2:mem:testdb" worked for me as well

Answer (score 10):

You need to register bean for showing h2 console like:

```
@Bean   
public ServletRegistrationBean h2servletRegistration() {        
        ServletRegistrationBean registrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(new WebServlet());       
        registrationBean.addUrlMappings("/console/*");      
        return registrationBean;    
}
```

and invoke the H2 console from browser like:

http://localhost:8080/console

**Note:** Port number will be port on which your spring boot application is running

Add below lines to application.properties

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.platform=h2
spring.datasource.driverClassName = org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/test;
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
```

Comment: the application.properties configuration really worked for me,Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Since default url is different. Its not showing in your particular DS.
Add below to your `application.properties` file under `src/main/resources`

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
```

Answer (score 2):

Try annotating the main class with @EntityScan("packageName");

If you entity is in com.example package over the class of main method write @EntityScan("com.example");

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the url exactly like you have it defined in application.properties.

In my case url was: spring.datasource.url:jdbc:h2:./test/test.service;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=100000

So I just changed the url in web console to jdbc:h2:./test/test.service and my tables appeared.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue. But the fix was really very small.
Please refer page : https://springframework.guru/using-the-h2-database-console-in-spring-boot-with-spring-security/  for more details.

In my case, I have added scope of H2 dependency as "runtime". I removed it and it fixed my issue. Not I am able to see tables in H2-console.

Previous dependency in my pom was :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

And new dependency which fixed my issue :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

IN spring 2020-09 it is compulsory to use schema.sql as the file name for creating a table
and data.sql for inserting data and if you don't your data will not show in the h2-database.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar issue, H2 console was enabled with the below settings
Driver Class: org.h2.Driver
JDBC URL: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
still I was unable to see the table I created inside the data.sql file.
I found two solutions, and both works well for me

1. Add the following property in application.properties file.
   spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
2. Rename the sql file to schema.sql, if you are using Spring Boot
   2.5.0 or Greater

Comment: adding reference links to documentation will help.