# Default configuration of H2 in-memory database set up by Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2, in-memory-database

I am using H2 database with Spring Boot (version 2.3.3.RELEASE) with all default settings for H2 database.

Here are the all files of my application.

**pom.xml**

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
```

**Application.java**

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;

import java.sql.SQLException;

@SpringBootApplication
public class App {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
 }
```

}

After starting the application when i am trying to connect the H2 database (configured and started by springboot with all default configuration) using below credentials,

[image: H2-Console]

I am getting error saying

> Database "mem:testDB" not found, either pre-create it or allow remote
> database creation

How can I connect to H2 database configured and started by Spring Boot with all the default credentials.

I don't want to override any configuration in `application.properties` files except `spring.h2.console.enabled=true`.

Comment: Try lowercase: `jdbc:h2:mem:testdb`

Comment: what's the spring.datasource.url value you have supplied, based on that it will configure the in memory db

Comment: I haven't supplied any property like "spring.datasource.url". I want to let spring configure the DB with default configuration. @Selindek : Also i tried with "jdbc:h2:mem:testdb" all in lower case but still getting the same error

Comment: try jdbc:h2:~/test because h2 creates a test db under your Users directory automatically. Check out the quickstart: https://www.h2database.com/html/quickstart.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [spring boot default H2 jdbc connection (and H2 console)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24655684/spring-boot-default-h2-jdbc-connection-and-h2-console)

Answer (score 2):

In newer version of Spring Boot (2.2+), look for the following log message on your console: Use the JDBC URL to connect on `/h2-console` page:

**Spring Boot 2.2+:**

`INFO H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration  : H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:mem:testdb'`

**Spring Boto 2.3+:**

`INFO H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration  : H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:mem:621dd224-01db-4137-807f-b9c3046de64d'`

Comment: The answer is correct, the table name is shown on spring init log.

Answer (score -1):

Only enabling console wouldn't be sufficient, you also need to mention which db you want connect. In your case if you want connect in memory db add below properties as well, then try to connect your in memory db using same creds

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
```