# h2 console access with spring 4

Tags: hibernate, h2

I'm using spring 4 with hibernate and h2 db or integration tests. However, when the tests run, I can't seem to view the created tables in the h2 db. `jdbc:h2:mem:test` is the url. I have downloaded the h2 console and try to access the db via the url `http://192.168.1.103:8082/login.do?jsessionid=07eb821d275e177f5f2a64aedc682d0b`. This opens up the console but I do not see any of the urls. How can I get the tables from the tests into the console.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [spring boot default H2 jdbc connection (and H2 console)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24655684/spring-boot-default-h2-jdbc-connection-and-h2-console)

Comment: This is all about spring boot right? I’m looking for spring 4